# One Column values will be changed when header DropdownListFor is getting changed - in mvc razor view c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-ajax

new to this type of work , need your help

in my view  .cshtml ----

```
<table class>

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th >@Html.CheckBox("IsAllRowSelected")</th>
                        <th >
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m._dropDownForcolumn2, new List<SelectListItem>
                   { new SelectListItem{Text="option1", Value="option1"},
                       new SelectListItem{Text="option2", Value="option2"},
                       new SelectListItem{Text="option3", Value="option3"}
                     }, new {@id="dropDownForcolumn2" })
                        </th>
                        <th>@Html.Label(" column 3 ")</th>
                        <th>@Html.Label("column 4")</th>
                        <th>@Html.Label("column 5")</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (Models.MyModelClass item in Model._List)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.CheckBox("IsEachRowSelected")</td>
                            <td>@item.Option1Values</td> 
 @*//@item.option2values; 
@item.option3vlaues;*@
                            <td>@item.column3value</td>
                            <td>@item.column4value</td>
                            <td>@item.column5value</td>

                        </tr>
                    }
```

1 .cant post back to controller again to get only this column values . its just a small table in a huge page 
2 i already have the other values in item
 now only option1 values are coming in the column , the requirement is to bind 2nd colmn with header dropdown and 2nd option selected then this will show @item.option2values and 3rd option selected then @item.option3values will be shown

other columns will not be changed or touched   .

somthing like this

```
<td>
      if(dropdownvalue = option1)
       @item.Option1Values
elseif(dropdownvalue == option2 )
     @item.option2values 
elseif(dropdownvalue == option2 )
    @item.option3vlaues
</td>
```

ajax  , jquery is allowed but whole page post or partial view post is not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it like this 
 put onload method in table tag

```
function load()
{

    $('.MyProperty2').hide();
    $('.MyProperty3').hide();
}

function Filldropdown(){


    var value = $('#dropdownID :selected').text();


    if (value == 'option1') {

        $('.MyProperty1').show();
        $('.MyProperty2').hide();
        $('.MyProperty3').hide();

    } else if (value == 'option2') {
        $('.MyProperty2').show();
        $('.MyProperty1').hide();
        $('.MyProperty3').hide();

    } else if (value == 'option3')  {
        $('.MyProperty3').show();
        $('.MyProperty2').hide();
        $('.MyProperty1').hide();


    }


}
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for